# Tipping for an expensive item that comes with minimal service,

Tags: services

A couple days ago, a rich NBA basketball player (I think he signed a new 30 million dollar contract just days ago) bought a bottle of liquor from the bar counter, was charged nearly 500 dollars for it, and he gave the bartender a 13 dollar tip, which was about a 2% tip.

He was "outed" on social media by the bartender, but the athlete defended himself by saying that he gave 13 dollars in tip for minimal service.  (He brought the bottle over to his friends, there was no table service, and they were not at a nightclub.)

Which leads to my question:  what should one do in such a situation?  Is it ridiculous to pay 20% tip on an almost 500 dollar bottle of liquor that comes with no service by the bartender?

For me personally, I have had this dilemma at steakhouses; I order a 100 dollar porterhouse steak, which the waiter just puts on my table and goes away, and there is virtually no service.  (I don't order wine or appetizers or desserts or anything else.)  Do I have to pay 20% tip on a 100 dollar meal?  Or, pay something less, say, 5 to 10 dollars?

Thanks,

Comment: The real solution is for bars/restaurants to pay their staff fairly and do away with tipping altogether (not likely to happen anytime soon unfortunately). The fact is, a tip is and always be completely optional, so there can never be a "right" or "wrong" amount, there will only ever be people's opinions for each.

Comment: `100 dollar porterhouse steak` Whoa !! Is it decked in gold ??

Comment: @CactusCake, many states and counties have done away with a tip-credited minimum wage, long gone are the days of the diner waitress making $2+tips.  It's baffling that food service has continued on with this custom.

Comment: Most places that charge $100 for a porterhouse offer unbelievable excellent service.  For example, I am typically happy with the service at Longhorn, and their porterhouse is $28.  Capital Grille, is just on a different level and theirs is $52.   If you insist on going to a high end steak house, then yes you should tip 20% in all but the extreme cases.  Its not like you are going back to the kitchen to pick up your order.

Comment: If the server used a crumb scraper on the tablecloth after clearing a plate, or refolded your napkin if you got up to use the restroom, that's steakhouse/white tablecloth "service" that is not typical in lower price point restaurants.  Such a server may also have skills in tableside deboning, bananas foster, caesar salad or steak tartare preparation, wine recommendation, etc.

Comment: I suspect that the server has received his last and only tip from the customer and his NBA friends. Cut off nose; spite face.

Comment: @user662852 has a point, staff at restaurants that sell $100 steaks are generally going to be more skilled, be dressed in better uniforms that cost money to dry clean?, etc. Maybe even be more attractive or polite. Competition for those jobs is going to be a bit fiercer because the pay is effectively higher, and/or each waitperson is assigned fewer tables. There will be more cooks and whatnot behind the scenes and the waitperson probably has to split the tip with them. Therefore if you tip $5 on a $100 steak you are not holding up your end of the deal.

Comment: Also, while I don't usually order drinks, I try to tip as if I had ordered a drink. The waiter still has to bring me water and refill it more than he would have if I ordered a drink. The same would apply at a steakhouse where you don't order any a la carte sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've long held that a percentage-based tip standard is silly. I tip based on service and, if at a restaurant, how long I'm occupying the table.

My wife and I frequently split a $15 meal at a local Mexican restaurant. They keep the chips/salsa coming and drinks filled, and are always quick and courteous, we're usually in and out in half an hour. I like to tip ~$6-8 there.

I might tip more on a $100 meal because we're likely to sit at the table longer,  but if the service is poor then the tip reflects that. Many more expensive restaurants do have better service, but no guarantees.

> Do I have to pay 20% tip on a 100 dollar meal? Or, pay something less, say, 5 to 10 dollars?

Some people refuse to tip, some people always do a certain percentage, there is no wrong answer, it's purely subjective. You don't have to do anything but pay your bill.

Comment: I have given 50% tips like you do at the Mexican restaurant, when the bill is small and service is great. There's no law against tipping extra. However, you really have to consider carefully if you go below a 15% tip at a sit down, table service restaurant.

Answer (score 3):

I used to deliver pizzas. One time I delivered a $175 order to the richest person in the city. (They owned all the shopping malls.) It was the son who was having a pool party and he gave me two hundred dollar bills and asked for $5 in change. Even though that $20 tip was the largest tip I ever received and of course I was grateful, I was slightly disappointed that this super rich person asked for change as I wondered why he needed that $5.

On the other hand, occasionally I worked inside the restaurant and every once in a while someone would tip $1 on a pickup order. I was always *extremely* grateful when that happened.

> Conclusion: I think how satisfied someone is by a tip is based more on
>   expectation than anything else.

In the sited case, I agree with the tipper- no service was provided so the $13 tip should (probably) have been a pleasant surprise. But from the cashier's POV, she was expecting more simply due to his fame and fortune.

I might suggest as a rule of thumb: Tip what you feel is appropriate, but if you're famous, you should always tip well or else be willing to face the wrath of social media.

Comment: He did give you a 10% tip, so why the disappointment of returning $5 ? Were you being greedy ? Just because his parents are rich doesn't mean the child also has free money. Probably his parents are sane and give him only enough for what he really needs and no more. Or he is very careful with his money and doesn't go overboard spending money. There are ample reasons why he wanted the 5 bucks.

Comment: @DumbCoder - I was super happy to get a $20 tip. (I'm sure I said something like "Wow, Thank you so much!".) I was disappointed because I was *expecting* more. Maybe on my drive over I was fantasizing about a huge tip, or maybe when I saw the 2 hundreds I immediately thought "woohoo - I'm gonna get a $25 tip!". In retrospect I probably was being greedy. (I was 16.) But the point of my answer was simply that satisfaction is based on expectation, not necessarily reality.